# Why is this line not a horizontal shift of its parent function? If it is, how can I prove that?

Tags: functions, transformation

I took an algebra 1 quiz with a question that asked whether it was true or false that a line was a translation 3 units to the left of its parent function. I wrote an equation representing the transformation of f(X) into m(X) in which I applied a horizontal shift of 3 units to the left. When I checked the equation for accuracy to the graph, everything was correct. However, I was marked incorrect, and was told that the transformation was a vertical shift down 2 units. However, the horizontal shift and vertical shift create the exact same line, which is why I don’t understand why I’m incorrect. If I am correct, how can I prove that?
[Image of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsPwq.jpg)

Comment: Once a teacher *emotionally digs their heels in*, you might as well give up.  That is, if the teacher was emotionally open to your perspective, they would have taken the responsibility, up front, to analytically determine whether your assertion is accurate.  The fact that they ducked the issue speaks volumes.

Comment: It's both a vertical shift down two units and a horizontal shift left three units. In fact every vertical shift of a line will also be a horizontal shift of a line as well. It's one of the reasons lines are so special.